# angularjs not responding the GET method

Tags: django, angularjs

i am relatively new in django and angualarJs.The problem is that angularJs is not responding  the get method properly.I have a webpage developed by django where i have a search field.For the execution of search i use a angularJs functionality that is ng-submit and write angularJs code to return value using get method.May be i made a mistake here.you can see my code... here is my template which containing the angularJs also...

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default " ng-controller="NavCtrl">
    <form action="" class="navbar-form navbar-right" ng-submit="search()">
        <input class="form-control col-lg-8" type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="term"></input>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    app.controller("NavCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$q', '$timeout',
        function NavCtrl($scope, $http, $location, $q, $timeout) {
            $scope.results = ["Test"];
            $scope.term = "";
            $scope.reqs = "5";
            $scope.pics = "45";
            $scope.ddata = "asdasd";
            $scope.ddata = $http.post("{% url 'get-nav-info' %}").success(
                function (result) {
                    //$scope.reqs = result.data.data.num_request;
                    //$scope.pics = result.data.data.num_photo;
                    return result.data;
                }
            );
            //$scope.reqs = $scope.ddata.num_request;
            //$scope.pics = $scope.ddata.num_photo;

            $scope.search = function () {
                //alert("test");
                //$location.absUrl("{% url 'search-term-show' %}").search({'term':$scope.term}).apply();
                //$location.path("{% url 'search-term-show' %}").search({'term':$scope.term}).apply();
                $http.get("{% url 'search-term-show' %}?term=" + $scope.term).success(function (result) {
                    return result.data;
                });
                //$scope.$apply();
            }
        }
    ]);
</script>
```

now the problem is that while i press enter ,there is no result,but if i manually write this  URL which is **http://www.kothay.com/searchphoto/?term=a** in the address bar then the result is showing .In mention,this url is the that url which should be appear in the address bar when i press the enter to search my photos.But with the enter press its not appearing in the address bar and that's why the results are not showing.I hope you can understand what i am trying to say.May be there is a mistake in my code.Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: I think you need to save your `result.data` in a scope when `success` callback is called.

Comment: can you please give me the solution in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing thing wrong.

1st, the success is a defer of get, so return result.data and returns it to the get deferred and there it goes to the heaven. So if you would like to keep the current architecture it should look more like this

```
$scope.search = [];
getsearch = function () {
                $http.get("{% url 'search-term-show' %}?term=" + $scope.term).success(function (result) {
                    $scope.search = result.data;
                });
            };
getsearch();
```

2nd that can still not update your UI cuz if the ctrl function is over and the digest is over before your response it wont update your UI cuz its in another scope (not $scope, but the programmatically term scope). The solution to this is to put your data in a service and in your ctr just do.

```
function ctrl($scope, myservice){
  $scope.data = myservice;
}
ng-repeat="x in data.results"
```

Here is a full tutorial http://bresleveloper.blogspot.co.il/2013/08/breslevelopers-angularjs-tutorial.html

And last thing its just a good practice to always have .error(...)

Comment: I wanted it to load a new page, but it still is not loading a new page against getsearch(). If I inspect it, I see that it is working (200 OK) against the request.

Comment: user a service, here is a full tutorial

Comment: where is a full tutorial?

Comment: sry,  http://bresleveloper.blogspot.co.il/2013/08/breslevelopers-angularjs-tutorial.html